# Enumerating permissions in WSS 3.0

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0

1) I have inherited a WSS 3.0 site that HR has run wild with, and they've got permissions all over the place with around 40 different groups and then another 10-15 users per site with explicitly-granted permissions (vice adding them to the groups).

Other than manually clicking through every subsite to see where inheritance is broken and what permissions are changed, is there an easier way to enumerate the permissions for each site in a readable format?

Thank  you!

2) As a follow-on, how would you manage really complex permissions structures in WSS 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SharePoint Administration Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508851%28v=office.12%29) contains a Permission reporting tool

Comment: Great tool, love the check effective permissions that it adds everywhere.